# QProcess::readAllStandardOutput() and line feeds

Tags: c++, ubuntu, qt5, qstring, qbytearray

I'm printing output from `QProcess::readAllStandardOutput()` (on Ubuntu 18.04) and it works otherwise fine, but `\n` characters are not actually line feeds and somehow appear literally as a part of the string:

```
/usr/local/lib/libpcl_search.so\n/usr/local/lib/libpcl_sample_consensus.so\n/usr/local/lib/libpcl_io.so\n/usr/local/lib/libpcl_segmentation.so\n/usr/local/lib/libpcl_common.so\n/usr/local/lib/libboost_random.so\n/usr/local/lib/libboost_math_tr1l.so
```

That was output when running `find / -name "*so"` command with QProcess printed like this:

```
qDebug() << m_process->readAllStandardOutput();
```

I guess this is an encoding issue..?

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you are reading/viewing the data from the `QProcess`.

Comment: Edited. Not sure why the downvotes.

Comment: Keep in mind that depending on the command you will have an answer, on the other hand readAllStandardOutput() returns a QByteArray() not a QString() so you probably get the `\n`

Comment: Yeah, but look at the answer I posted myself.

Comment: As stated by @eyllanesc, the `qDebug` `operator<<` overload for `QByteArray` will escape certain characters such as newlines etc.  Hence the output you see.

Comment: Do you know why `startDetached()` behaves differently, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is caused because QDebug is going to show the endlines and similar characters because you are passing them a QByteArray, if you want to see the output you want then use qPrintable:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QProcess process;

    QObject::connect(&process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [&process](){
        qDebug()<< qPrintable(process.readAllStandardOutput());
    });
    process.start("find / -name \"*so\"");

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
/snap/core/4917/lib/crda/libreg.so
/snap/core/4917/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
/snap/core/4917/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libBrokenLocale-2.23.so
/snap/core/4917/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSegFault.so
/snap/core/4917/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libanl-2.23.so
/snap/core/4917/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
/snap/core/4917/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcidn-2.23.so
...
```

Comment: I'm still wondering why I don't have this problem when starting the process with `startDetached()`. In that case it also gets a QByteArray.

Comment: That depends on how you're calling, you could show a [mcve] of that case

Comment: Just replace process.start() in your code with process.startDetached()

Comment: as I see the source code the implementation is different and maybe that generates that difference.

Comment: But `QDebug` doesn't know that :)

Comment: qDebug only prints, does not know the source, if one prints a QByteArray expects to see all the characters as "\n" "\r" since one as a developer wants to analyze all the bytes, what I think happens is that the readAllStandardOutput() of start() and startDetached() are different, right now I'm doing tests to see the differences.

Comment: @juzzlin in startDetached the impression is sent to the console directly, comment on the qDebug() and you will see that it continues printing.